# Windows server restart / shut down

Tags: shutdown, windows-server-2012, reboot

Can any one tell me how to disable the popup that reads: "Choose a reason that best describes why you want to shut down this computer" on windows Server 2012? This consistently comes up whenever i need to restart or shutdown the server.

I am assuming it still performs a simple restart no matter what i choose, so i would rather not be asked every time.

Also i have found directions before on how to accomplish this, but it would only work on a server that was apart of a Domain, and mine is not.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable the Shutdown Event Tracker.

In an AD domain you can use the GPMC to modify the applicable GPO.

On a standalone server you can use GPEDIT.msc to modify local Group Policy.

Here's an article that describes both methods:

http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/windows_server/server-2012-shutdown-event-tracker.htm

Answer (score 2):

This message is linked to the [Shutdown Event Tracker](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732119.aspx).

You can access it by running `gpedit.msc` then going to the **Local Computer Policy** navigation pane, expanding **Computer Configuration**, then expanding **Administrative Templates**, and clicking on **System**.

Then right-click **Display Shutdown Event Tracker**, and click **Properties**. In here you can set how and when you want the Shutdown Tracker to run.